# Error Deploying Chainlink Data Feed Smart Contract on SepoliaTestnet Using WalletConnect in Remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, chainlink

I am new to blockchain developement and experimenting with chainlink Data Feed example smart contract that obtains the latest price from BTC/USD.  I tried to deploy the contract on Sepolia testnet using "Wallet Connect" environment option in remix. The transaction fails with following error. Can anyone help please

creation of DataConsumerV3 pending...
creation of DataConsumerV3 errored: Missing or invalid parameters.
Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org
Request body: {"method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x5b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4","data":"0x6.....","value":"0x0","gas":"0x2dc6c0","type":"0x2","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x9502F900","maxFeePerGas":"0x9898f120"}]}

Details: unknown account
Version: viem@1.2.12

community help
exisiting solution,

Comment: Are you sure you input the parameters to deploy the contract correctly?

Comment: yes, I am certain. Actually, I don't enter these input parameters but are programmed in the contract.